# datefield not showing a default value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I tried using a `DateField` and show a default value, but it does not show on the page (but in the HTML):

```
class foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {"date": DateInput(format=("%d-%m-%Y"), attrs={"class": "form-control", "value": timezone.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "type": "date"}),}
```

this produces:

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="29-02-2024" class="input" prod_date="input" required="" id="id_date">
```

which shows as:

[image]

But not with the current date as placeholder.

Edit:
After editing like suggested I see in the admin that this works:
[image]
But the template for the normal page still shows no placeholder.

I used:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {"date": DateInput(format=("%d-%m-%Y"), attrs={"class": "form-control", "type": "date"}),}
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the widget is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so `2024-02-29` in this case. That being said, **don't** set the value through the widget attributes: one of the tasks of the form (fields) is converting Python values to the corresponding value in the widget, so essentially you are duplicating boilerplate logic, and as you found out yourself, this conversion is often quite complicated:

```
from datetime import date


class Foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)


class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput(
                format=('%d-%m-%Y'),
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'},
            ),
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your input - unfortunately I still end up with the same placeholder only showing `mm / dd / yyyy`.

Comment: @xtlc: you did add the `default=...` to the model field, and removed the `value` from the `attrs`?

Comment: I updated my code in my question, but yes, I did that - and I see it is doing something, because the admin has changed. But the front page still has the same problem - no correct placeholder.

Comment: I got it to work switching the `format=('%d-%m-%Y')` to `format=('%Y-%m-%d')` (mind the position of the `Y` formatter). Unfortunately it now is displayed in mm-dd-yyyy which is unreadable and should obviously be dd-mm-yyyy